# Alert not getting inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, alert, getelementbyid

I am trying to get my java script file to capture the inner Html of an id in my HTML file and alert it.

here is my html code

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="indexjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topbar">
 <ul>
  <li id="barmuhia">Job Muhia</li>
</ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

the js code  is

```
alert(GetElementById("barmuhia").innerHTML)
```

Comment: Should be `alert(document.getElementById("barmuhia").innerHTML)`

Comment: also, if the JS code is inside indexjs.js, that will attempt to run before that element exists

Comment: You should see a relevant error message in the console of your browser's dev tools. That would typically be the first stage of debugging something like this.

Comment: my bad, i forgot to include the document part before getElementById. i have fixed that..but it is still not working... i think it also got something to do with jaramonda X comment. how do i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You are missing **document** and using GetElementById instead of getElementById  here, use below

```
alert(document.getElementById("barmuhia").innerHTML);
```

you can also use below jquery method

```
$("#barmuhia").html()
```

Answer (score 6):

The actual method name is `getElementById` and it is in the document object.
See [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Change `GetElementById` first letter to lower case and prefix with document - `document.getElementById`.

**Example**

```js
alert("js file connected");
alert(document.getElementById("barmuhia").innerHTML);
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="topbar">
      <ul>
        <li id="barmuhia">Job Muhia</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

**Updated**

**index.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
      // your code goes here
}
```

Or

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <ul>
            <li id="barmuhia">Job Muhia</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="indexjs.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i have fixed it..but its still not working. how do i fix the js file running before the element existing.

Comment: Put your script at the bottom of the body tag, or use `window.onload` , wrap your code into a function and give that reference to `window.onload`

Answer (score 4):

`GetElementById` isn't method

Switch to `getElementById()` or use jQuery `$("#element").html()`;

Comment: thank you @suresh Atta .. i have added all the possible codes of solution..my js file looks like this now..           alert('js file connected');
alert(document.getElementById("barmuhia").innerHTML);
$("#barmuhia").html() ;            only the first line of alert is working

Comment: @MJob If that helped - mark this answer as a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert(document.getElementById("barmuhia").innerHTML);
```

```html
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="indexjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topbar">
 <ul>
  <li id="barmuhia">Job Muhia</li>
</ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve it out through your help.

first, it was so silly of me to not realized that i had changed the content of #barmuhia to an img element. i changed it back to a normal text element but it still didn't work. i used one of the solutions provided above to put the alerts in a function which will only call after the my webpage is loaded.

```
window.onload = function () {
  alert('js file connected')
alert(document.getElementById("barmuhia").innerHTML) }
```

Thank you all.